# Getting a BitMap returned from AsyncTask in Java

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I am having trouble understanding AsyncTask. I am sending a file location to it so that it can retrieve it, resize it and return it. When I call the asynctask class from my activity, which is a BaseAdapter ListView I am getting a type mismatch.

I thought that I could return the Bitmap from the execute. I have read that I need to use the onPostExecute() but am unsure how..

```
public class ImageHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        Bitmap sizedBMP = null;
        @Override

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

            File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath(), "/"+params[0]+"/"+params[0]+".png");
            if (imgFile.exists()){
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.toString());
                int newWidth = 500;
                sizedBMP = getResizedBitmap(bmp, newWidth);

            }
            else{
                //set no image available
            }
            return sizedBMP;

        }

        @Override
        // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap sizedBMP) {

        }


    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth) {
        // Bitmap gets resized here.....

        }
}
```

I am calling this class inside the getView() like:

```
ImageHandler imgHandler = new ImageHandler();
Bitmap bitMap;
bitMap = imgHandler.execute(filename);
```

Error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask to
>   Bitmap

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) or any other image loading library?

Comment: Well, someone suggested glide, but I wanted to learn how to make it work  myself I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `.execute` returns the current AsyncTask. To set the result, add a constructor with parameter the imageview you want to use to show the bitmap.

```
public class ImageHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        Bitmap sizedBMP = null;
        ImageView imageView;

        public ImageHandler(ImageView imageView){
             this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

            File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath(), "/"+params[0]+"/"+params[0]+".png");
            if (imgFile.exists()){
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.toString());
                int newWidth = 500;
                sizedBMP = getResizedBitmap(bmp, newWidth);

            }
            else{
                //set no image available
            }
            return sizedBMP;

        }

        @Override
        // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap sizedBMP) {
                if(sizedBMP != null){
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(sizedBMP);
                }
        }


    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth) {
        // Bitmap gets resized here.....

        }
}
```

and then set the imageView in the constructor like this way:

```
ImageHandler imgHandler = new ImageHandler(myImageView);
imgHandler.execute(filename);
```

That should works but if you want to use this type of image loader, when scroll the listview you may have other problem - for a single ImageView slot in a row few bitmaps will replace each other for few seconds.

[This](http://android-developers.blogspot.bg/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) topic can help you with that.